# Ordering results returned from table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a user defined function that returns a table. The problem is that this table needs to be sorted based on complex criteria and due to this it shouldn't be sorted by the function caller but needs to be sorted in the function itself.

Simplified example

```
select * 
from custom_function('param1', 'param2' ...) 
order by 
complex criteria 1,
complex criteria 2....
```

Is it possible to move order by into function and to get ordered results from select?

Comment: `complex criteria` means

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY complex criteria 1, complex criteria 2...) AS fROW_NUMBER` in your function and then `ORDER BY fROW_NUMBER` in your query...??? Far too vague a question here.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause must be specified in the query that uses the function. An `ORDER BY` within the function will not guarantee ordering of results when the function is used.

Comment: The **only** `ORDER BY` clause that is respected for determining the order of rows in a result set is the one applied at the *outermost* level of the query. You **cannot** do something within the function that will change this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't sort the table directly, but you can add a column specifying the ordering.  So, define the function as:

```
select . . .,
       row_number() over (order by <complex ordering criteria>) ord
. . .
```

Then you can call it as:

```
select f.*
from dbo.func(. . .) f
order by ord;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use order by as shown below. Let the Table-Valued Function be:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION ReturnTableTOrder()
    RETURNS @returnList TABLE (Col1 char(1), Col2 int)
    AS
    BEGIN   

         INSERT INTO @returnList
         SELECT 'A',5 Union All
         SELECT 'D',2 Union All
         SELECT 'B',4 Union All
         SELECT 'E',1 Union All
         SELECT 'C',3 

     RETURN

    END
```

You can order by Column Ordinal Position

```
    Select * from ReturnTableTOrder()
    Order by 1
```

o/p

```
Col1  Col2
 A     5
 B     4
 C     3
 D     2
 E     1
```

and for below query,

```
    Select * from ReturnTableTOrder()
    Order by 2
```

output is

```
Col1  Col2
 E     1
 D     2
 C     3
 B     4
 A     5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this, if you are prepared to accept unique sorted results, is to add a PK to the return table.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION MyFunc ()
    RETURNS @tblArray TABLE (Element VARCHAR(900) PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON))

AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @tblArray VALUES ('c'),('b'),('a')  
    RETURN

END
```

This returns a recordset containing

```
Element
a
b
c
```

Note: This question is old but it hasn't been answered properly yet, other than to say it can't be done except by adding a sort column, which isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: If you just do `SELECT * FROM MyFunc ()` this does not guarantee any order.  In fact it is very possible if `@tblArray` is large that the records will not be returned in key order. Table variables (such as `@tblArray`)  are not accessible to other connections so  [get an implicit `nolock` hint anyway](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/3690). This means that they meet the requirements to be eligible for an allocation ordered scan irrespective of isolation level in effect

Comment: As always the only way of *guaranteeing* a particular order of results is an `ORDER BY` on the outer query.

Comment: Good spot Martin. The largest number of rows for which this works on my system is 26,838. So the sort order is not guaranteed but it does seem to work - at least for a moderate number of records.

Comment: Despite the low score, this actually works to a degree and is a good answer.

Comment: Thank you Phil, that's good to hear :) If you found it useful please consider upvoting the answer.